# How to deploy a Bitnami chart on K8S with terraform passing a custom values.yaml?

Tags: terraform, kubernetes-helm, bitnami

Friends, I want to deploy a helm chart of bitnami with a custom values.yaml using Terraform.  Is this possible? While I was using only K8S and Helm, what I did was copying the values.yaml from the Bitnami repo, and changing what I needed and then run `helm install mysql -f values.yaml bitnami/mysql`. Now I have to deploy everything with terraform and I am wondering how I can do that. Do I have to clone the whole Bitnami repo and deploy it like the following?

```
resource "helm_release" "example" {
  name       = "my-local-chart"
  chart      = "./charts/example"
}
```

Or is it possible to deploy the chart passing my costum values.yaml? Any idea? I am super new to all this.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question,
**This is fairly possible with using terraform.**

**[ With Chart Repository]**

[Here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/helm/latest/docs/resources/release#example-usage---chart-repository) you can find how you can set custom `values.yaml` file itself. and also how to use a chart from a remote repository.

**[With Local Charts]**

and [here](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/using-the-kubernetes-and-helm-providers-with-terraform-0-12) you can find out how to specify a specific `value`, here they have shown mostly how to work with local charts(men's you should have the charts in your local file system and from terraform code you have to point to it, just like you given in the question.),

also for local charts, you can look at this [docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/helm/latest/docs/resources/release#example-usage---local-chart) as well.

Example:

Helm : `helm install mysql -f values.yaml bitnami/mysql`

Terraform:

```
resource "helm_release" "mysql" {
  name       = "mysql"
  repository = "https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami"
  chart      = "mysql"
  version    = "8.2.3"

  values = [
    "${file("values.yaml")}"
  ]

  set {
    name  = "metrics.enabled"
    value = "true"
  }

  set {
    name  = "service.annotations.prometheus.io/port" 
    value = "9127"
    type  = "string"
  }
}
```

in the above, I'm setting the values from custom `values.yaml` file although I'm overwriting the `metrics.enabled` and `service.annotations.prometheus.io/port`.